# Gutenberg: how to hide server side render output in the editor but keep it in frontend?

Tags: block-editor

My goal is to use the Gutenberg Block for the backend editor to collect the data but output it only with php.

I added a server-side-render component to my block. Now I can edit attributes in the Gutenberg Editor and output them on the server side with php. But the output is renderer in the editor as well. I don't need that because it displays everything twice. How do I hide the server side render output in editor?

Do I prevent the output in php with something like "if is_frontend() {return $output}" or is there an attribute for server side render to keep it off Gutenberg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be down in the php render_function. Check if it is an API REST request:

```
function create_block() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ ,[
        'render_callback' => 'render_php'
    ] );
}

function render_php(){
    

    if ( defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) && REST_REQUEST ) {
        return "<p>Backend says hello from php</p>";
    } else {
        return "<p>Frontend says hello from php</p>";
    };

    
}
```